# Shapeless generic ZipWith with static poly

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I have some code:

```
case class Name(name: String) extends StaticAnnotation

case class Example(@Name("baz") foo: String, bar: Int)

object nameAnnotationZip2 extends Poly2 {
  implicit val newName: Case.Aux[Symbol, Some[Name], String] =
    at((_, name) => name.value.name)

  implicit val existingName: Case.Aux[Symbol, None.type, String] =
    at((field, _) => field.name)
}

def renameRecord[
    A,
    Record <: HList,
    Fields <: HList,
    Annotations <: HList,
    ZippedWith <: HList
](a: A)(implicit
    generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, Record],
    fields: Keys.Aux[Record, Fields],
    annotations: Annotations.Aux[Name, A, Annotations],
    zippedWith: ZipWith.Aux[
      Fields,
      Annotations,
      nameAnnotationZip2.type,
      ZippedWith
    ]
) = {
  val record = generic.to(a)
  println(fields())
  println(annotations())
  zippedWith(fields(), annotations())
}

renameRecord(Example("qix", 5))
```

which attempts to create a record from an instance with renamed keys based on an annotation. unfortunately it always gives me a

> could not find implicit value for parameter zippedWith: shapeless.ops.hlist.ZipWith.Aux[Fields,Annotations,nameAnnotationZip2.type,ZippedWith]

I haven't added the `ZipWithKeys` bit yet, but I believe I need to work around this issue first.

I believe I'm simply using `Poly` totally wrong somehow, but the compiler message isn't helping me find my error.

edit/part two:
I can work around by using `Zip` instead of `ZipWith`, converting to `Sized`, simply mapping the seq without `Poly`, and converting back to `HList`. what's the runtime performance difference between doing that and the above?

Answer (score 2):

The type of `Fields` isn't `Symbol`, it's `Symbol @@ "foo"`. `Case`'s generic parameters aren't variant so `nameAnnotationZip2` isn't defined for the elements of `Fields`.

Adding a generic parameter to the cases fixes the issue

```scala
object nameAnnotationZip2 extends Poly2 {
  implicit def newName[K <: Symbol]: Case.Aux[K, Some[Name], String] =
    at((_, name) => name.value.name)

  implicit def existingName[K <: Symbol]: Case.Aux[K, None.type, String] =
    at((field, _) => field.name)
}
```